# Function Sequence Uniform Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Just wondering if anyone has an example of a (complex) function sequence $(f_n)$ which is uniformly convergent, but the sequence of cubes $(f_n^3)$ is not uniformly convergent?

Comment: On which domain? If on a compact, that will not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

How about $f_n(x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$?