# Example of uniformly convergent sequence $(f_{n})$ such that the sequence of cubes $(f^3_{n})$ does not converge uniformly on the same set

Tags: complex-analysis

So I know if the sequence $f_{n}$ has a pointwise limit $f(z)=z$ then the convergence is uniform on $C$ iff

$\sup\|(f_{n}(z)-f(z))|$$\rightarrow$  0 as n tends to infinity

My trouble is in finding an example of a sequence is that is uniformly convergent and so is its sequence of cubes. Any help?

Note: Sorry about my English!

Comment: Which behavior do you have in mind for the sequence of the cubes? The one from the title or the one from the actual question?

Comment: Remarkably similar to this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285562/function-sequence-uniform-convergence/2285566#2285566

Comment: Sorry! I was looking for $sup|f^3_{n}(z)-f^3(z)| \rightarrow 0$

Comment: But your title says the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

What about $f_n(z)=z$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: How does that work?  If $f_n(z)=z$ then $f(z)=z$ also.  Thus $f_n^3(z)=z^3$ and $f^3(z)=z^3$ so that $f_n^3-f^3=0$.

Comment: Correct. So $\sup|{f_n}^3(z)-f^3(z)|=0\to0$. Right? This is what the author said that he was looking for.

Comment: The request is for an example for which $f_n$ converges uniformly, but $f_n^3$ does not converge uniformly.  The example $z+1/n$ suffices, but not $z$.

Comment: Did you read the remark by the author? He is looking for $\sup|{f_n}^3(z)-f_n(z)|=0$. Therefore, he wants that the sequence $({f_n}^3)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge uniformly.